# A duplicate of question is on other SE site

Tags: feature-request, flagging, exact-duplicates

I have tried to flag a question as duplicate, because it has already an answer, but on other StackExchage site. However, the flag dialog showed error because this answer is not on here on security. Personally, I think that SQL-injection should be here on information security.

It is this question:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92521/can-anyone-give-me-sample-php-code-that-is-vulnerable-to-sql-injection

Why I cannot flag a question as duplicate, when it has answer on other SE site (where I think it should not be)?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172307/201081  :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That question is perfectly appropriate where it is. It would also be on topic here but that doesn't mean we would migrate it.

Flagging as dupe only works on the same site, but remember you can always flag as "other" and write the reason in the free text field. Mods still see it.